# A fundamental question about disjoint union topology

Tags: general-topology

According to the following link :

https://drexel28.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/disjoint-union-topology/

A disjoint union topology , the disjoint union is a collection of tuples of the form ($\ x$, $\ j$), where $\ x$ is an element which belongs to some set $\ X_j$ in the collection of topological spaces . What , if , the same element belongs to two different sets , i.e. , it is included in the intersection of two sets . Then in this case will the disjoint union contain two elements of the form ($\ x$,$\ j$) and ($\ x$,$\ i$) where $\ i$ $\ \neq$$\ j$ ?

Comment: Yes. That is why it is called the disjoint union. For a simple example, consider the disjoint union of a set with itself. There will be two copies of each element.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indeed. This is the function of the second component $i$, resp. $j$. We can have all the same spaces $X_i = X$ and still have $|I|$ (where $I$ is the index set of the $X_i$) many copies of that space, all disjoint (side by side essentially, no interaction between them).

Comment: Can’t imagine why this was downvoted; +1.